# Application to store/browse/view photos?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, media, home-server

I am looking for application which I can install on Ubuntu server and put my photos there. It can be by web interface, it can be by mounted samba disk.

What I require:

1. Ability to add tags to photos.
2. Ability to move photos. I.e. if I set photos directory to /home/photos, but then I want to move all photos to e.g. /home/common/photos - I don't want to lose all the tags.

I used to use FSpot and it was great, but it lacked point 2, and I lost everything :(

Comment: You should stick with F-Spot - you need to select "Write metadata to file" in Preferences then all your tags will be on the files themselves.

Comment: It didn't have such feature when I was using it. If it is there now, I'm very happy :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Picasa for Linux](http://picasa.google.com/linux/) should have these functions

Check this link for a [feature list](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=112056):

- Sync your Picasa 3 and Picasa Web Albums edits

  - Tired of having to manually re-upload your photos after making further edits? By enabling 'Sync to Web,' edits made to your photos in Picasa 3 are automatically transferred to your corresponding online albums.
- Retouch your images

  - Always want to be airbrushed? Use the Retouch tool to remove unsightly blemishes and improve photo quality. It can also help you to restore old photos with marks, water stains, and scratches to excellent condition.
- Add text or watermarks to your photos

  - You can easily personalize your photos using the Watermark and Text tools.
- Print captions

  - Your captions are about to see a little more action. You can now print your captions or photo file names on or below your photos.
- Upload easily to Picasa Web Albums

  - Use the Drop Box to hold quick uploads and upload throttling to multi-task during your upload.
- Control your Picasa Web Albums settings

  - If you have an online album in Picasa Web Albums, you can now control the online settings through the corresponding folder or album in Picasa 3.
- Manage folders on your computer

  - It's now possible to move entire folders around on your hard drive from within Picasa 3.
- Get more information about your photos

  - We've added new icons and tools to the Library view to quickly communicate useful information about your photos.

Edit: changed the link!

Comment: That's not a good Picasa link - it goes straight to a Debian package download. Should be: http://picasa.google.com/linux/

Comment: Changed it ;) Happy now?

Comment: Can I tag photos in picasa? (I mean ones on my disk, not on web)

Comment: Crap it seems it can only do it on the Web version :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if [digiKam](http://www.digikam.org/) has some "server" features like you'd like.
Your best bet would probably be to try some web based gallery system such as [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the software you were using was associating tags with images in its own files, instead of using **IPTC Keywords**, which are embedded in the image file itself.

So you'll want to look into software that does exactly that: **tag images in the file's metadata.** This way, if you ever move your files, the tag will stick.

On WinXP, the two applications I use for organizing photos do this job pretty well: Photoshop Elements 6 and ACDSee. There's a couple more examples [there](http://microstockinsider.com/guides/keyword-setting-software-iptc).

Bonus: If you ever want to upload your images to a smart website (i.e [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/)), the tags will automatically be imported.

Comment: This is just what F-Spot does, but you need to select "Write metadata to file" in the F-Spot Preferences dialog.

Answer (score 0):

[piwigo](http://piwigo.org/) looks like a very good solution to manage photos. It's a php application with a very nice interface and modules.